# Mongo $expr return when delta of 2 fields exceeds 20%

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, bson

This will return docs where `field1` is greater that `field2`

`collection.find( { $expr: { $gt: [ "$field1" , "$field2" ] } } )`

I want to get documents where difference between `field1` and `field2` is greater or less than 20. Can that be done?

something like this.

```
{
  match: {
    $expr: {
      {
        $expr: {
          $gt: [
            $subtract: ["$field1", "$field2"], 20
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

***not looking for an aggregation solution***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can just use a similar query to what you're already doing, you just have to check both ways `field1 - field2 > 20` or `field2 - field1 > 20`.

You can easily achieve this using `$abs` `(absolute(field1 - field2) > 20)`, like so:

```
db.collection.find({
  $expr: {
    $gt: [
      {
        $abs: {
          $subtract: [
            "$field1",
            "$field2"
          ]
        }
      },
      20
    ]
  }
})
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/w1y4cLOzHtA)

Comment: if one of my fields is deep. Is this how i would write it `"$subtract": [ "$pirce", "$meta.amzItem.recommended" ]`